# Best way to encapsulate Animate callbacks?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm doing an animation using raphaeljs, have an element that must be positioned in different places and at different time, the problem I made using a callback within another and the code was extensive, there's a way to improve?

```
 var c = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);
    var p = c.path("m 40.008929,132.36161 0,128.5625 148.562501,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562501,0 z").attr({
        fill: '#33CCFF',
        stroke: '#000000',
        'stroke-width': 5
    });

    p.animate({
        path: "m 62.866072,140.93304 0,128.5625 148.562498,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562498,0 z"
    }, 2000, function () {

        p.animate({
            path: "m 77.151786,166.64733 0,128.5625 148.562494,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562494,0 z"
        }, 800, function () {

            p.animate({
                path: "m 71.4375,340.93304 0,128.5625 148.56249,0 0,-128.5625 -148.56249,0 z"
            }, 400, function () {

                p.animate({
                    path: "m 40.008929,132.36161 0,128.5625 148.562501,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562501,0 z"
                }, 1000);

            });

        });
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7d3Z/215/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array with the paths, and another array with the times.

then you create a function that calls p.animate with the next path and the next time, and with the same function as callback.

something like this:

```
var times = [2000,800,400,1000];
var paths = ["m 62.866072,140.93304 0,128.5625 148.562498,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562498,0 z",
             "m 77.151786,166.64733 0,128.5625 148.562494,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562494,0 z", 
             "m 71.4375,340.93304 0,128.5625 148.56249,0 0,-128.5625 -148.56249,0 z",
             "m 40.008929,132.36161 0,128.5625 148.562501,0 0,-128.5625 -148.562501,0 z" ];
var current=0;

function nextStep(){
    if (current>paths.length)
       return;
    p.animate({
        path: paths[current]
    }, times[current++],nextStep);


}
```

and you first launch it just by directly calling:

```
nextStep();
```

Your code will stay simple even if the animation has a lot of diferent movements, and the data is easier to read, since all the paths are together.

Comment: Hi Carlos, Your example was perfect thanks, but messed me when I had to make the animation paths in groups http://jsfiddle.net/dxyJN/2/ 
the element being shown when I want to be animated, thanks.

Comment: i get lost at this point, i cannot find what is happening with the groups :(